# react-icon-cloud gives Attempted import error

Tags: reactjs, tag-cloud

I am trying to use react-icon-cloud for the first time. I found the code in codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-kirch-mh5l4?file=/src/Componente.js copied and pasted it to my project, but got the error

```
    ./src/Home/Cloud.js
Attempted import error: 'IconCloud' is not exported from 'react-icon-cloud'.
```

tried deleting node_modules, tried restarting the server, but still got the same error.

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Here is the code

```
import React from "react";
import allIcons from "simple-icons";
import { v4 } from "uuid";
import { IconCloud } from "react-icon-cloud";

const Componente = () => {
  const tagCanvasOptions = {
    // activateAudio: string
    // activeCursor: string
    // altImage: boolean
    // animTiming: 'Smooth' | 'Linear'
    // audioIcon: boolean
    // audioIconDark: boolean
    // audioIconSize: number
    // audioIconThickness: number
    // audioVolume: number
    // bgColor: null | string
    // bgOutlineThickness: number
    // bgRadius: number
    // centreFunc: any
    // centreImage: any
    clickToFront: 500,
    // decel: number
    depth: 1,
    // dragControl: boolean
    // dragThreshold: number
    // fadeIn: number
    // freezeActive: boolean
    // freezeDecel: boolean
    // frontSelect: boolean
    // hideTags: boolean
    // imageAlign: 'centre' | 'left' | 'right'
    // imageMode: null | 'image' | 'text' | 'both'
    // imagePadding: number
    // imagePosition: 'top' | 'bottom' | 'left' | 'right'
    // imageRadius: number | string
    imageScale: 2,
    // imageVAlign: 'top' | 'bottom' | 'middle'
    initial: [0.1, -0.1],
    // interval: number
    // lock: null | 'x' | 'y' | 'xy'
    // maxBrightness: number
    // maxSpeed: number
    // minBrightness: number
    // minSpeed: number
    // minTags: 0 - 200
    // noMouse: boolean
    // noSelect: boolean
    // noTagsMessage: string
    // offsetX: number
    // offsetY: number
    outlineColour: "#0000",
    // outlineDash: number
    // outlineDashSpace: number
    // outlineIncrease: number
    // outlineMethod: 'outline' | 'classic' | 'block' | 'colour' | 'size' | 'none'
    // outlineOffset: number
    // outlineRadius: number
    // outlineThickness: number
    // padding: number
    // pinchZoom: boolean
    // pulsateTime: number
    // pulstateTo: number
    // radiusX: number
    // radiusY: number
    // radiusZ: number
    // repeatTagsTags: 0 - 64
    reverse: true,
    // scrollPause: boolean
    // shadow: string
    // shadowBlur: number
    // shadowOffset: [number,number] | number[]
    // shape: 'sphere' | 'hcylinder' | 'vcylinder' | 'hring' | 'vring'
    // shuffleTags: boolean
    // splitWidth: number
    // stretchX: number
    // stretchY: number
    // textAlign: 'centre' | 'left' | 'right'
    // textColour: string
    // textFont: string
    // textHeight: number
    // textVAlign: 'top' | 'bottom' | 'middle'
    tooltip: "native", // null | 'div'
    // tooltipClass: string
    tooltipDelay: 0,
    // txtOpt: boolean
    // txtScale: number
    // weight: boolean
    // weightFrom: any
    // weightGradient: any
    // weightMode: 'size' | 'colour' | 'both' | 'bgcolour' | 'bgoutline' | 'outline'
    // weightSize: number
    // weightSizeMax: number | null
    // weightSizeMin: number | null
    wheelZoom: false,
    // zoom: number
    // zoomMax: number
    // zoomMin: number
    // zoomStep: number
  };
  const iconSlugs = [
    "typescript",
    "javascript",
    "dart",
    "java",
    "react",
    "flutter",
    "android",
    "html5",
    "css3",
    "nodedotjs",
    "express",
    "nextdotjs",
    "prisma",
    "amazonaws",
    "postgresql",
    "firebase",
    "nginx",
    "vercel",
    "testinglibrary",
    "jest",
    "cypress",
    "docker",
    "git",
    "jira",
    "github",
    "gitlab",
    "visualstudiocode",
    "androidstudio",
    "sonarqube",
    "figma",
  ];
  const iconTags = iconSlugs.map((slug) => ({
    id: slug,
    simpleIcon: allIcons.Get(slug),
  }));
  return (
    <div>
      <IconCloud
        key={v4()}
        id={"icon"}
        minContrastRatio={1}
        iconSize={50}
        backgroundHexColor={"#fff"}
        fallbackHexColor={"#000"}
        tags={iconTags}
        tagCanvasOptions={tagCanvasOptions}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Componente;
```

Comment: Ensure that you are using the same version of react-icon-cloud library that is being used by the codesandbox example

Answer (score 1):

There is no `IconCloud` component exported in the library, if you are using the latest version of the package. Check the README of the library https://github.com/tsAppDevelopment/react-icon-cloud

It should be `Cloud`, you are looking to an outdated example, I suppose. In the README you can find an example and some links with demos.

Keep in mind that this library seems to be not so used, check if it is OK for your needs.

Comment: Thanks for your help. That fixed the error. But it shows no tags.

Comment: Check this https://github.com/tsAppDevelopment/react-icon-cloud#getting-started, you have to put tags as children of `Cloud`.

Comment: I am new to React and I am trying to convert it to React. I have downloaded https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-kirch-mh5l4?file=/src/Componente.js and run on localhost, it worked, but when I updated the packages react-icon-cloud it didn't work. It just shows "no tags".